# Given a four note combination under the span of a fourth, does this chart correctly show the number of times it will appear in a scale?

Tags: theory, harmony, modes, intervals

I have made this chart
that shows how many times will a four note combination under the span of a fourth whether perfect or augmented appear in a scale and some observations, so I wanted to ask you if this chart correctly reflects this and if my observations are correct or utterly wrong.
[image: dreadedchart]
[image: wrongserbations]

Comment: All this is very dependent on the definition of *tetrachord* - and that's where it all falls down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, regarding the number of times appearing in the scales.

Two comments about your observations section:

One, you refer to Gregorian modes, relative major/minor, natural minor, etc. *All* of that could be summed up as simply the *diatonic gamut* of `ABCDEFG`, which contains 2 major, 2 minor, 2 phrygian, and 1 lydian tetrachords.

When you mention that the diatonic gamut *contains* those tetrachords is sort of hints at looking at the tetrachords on each scale step, like this...

```
C - major tetrachord    CDEF
D - minor tetrachord    DEFG
E - phrygian tetrachord EFGA
F - lydian tetrachord   FGAB (not a P4 tetrachord)
G - major tetrachord    GABC
A - minor tetrachord    ABCD
B - phrygian tetrachord BCDE
```

While that is true, you will not be able to do the same thing with the non-diatonic scales. Consider, for example, `C` harmonic minor...

```
C  - C D Eb G  minor tetrachord
D  - D Eb F G  phrygian tetrachord
Eb - Eb F G Ab major tetrachord
F  - F G Ab B  (not a P4 tetrachord)
G  - G Ab B C  harmonic tetrachord
Ab - Ab B C D  (not a P4 tetrachord)
B  - B C D Eb  (not a P4 tetrachord)
```

That leads to the second point. When saying a scale *contains* various tetrachords, it sort of obscures the fact that a lot of the 4 tone sequences of various scale will *not* be P4 tetrachords.

A more common reference is to show which of the P4 tetrachords (major, minor, phrygian, and harmonic) separated by a P5 comprise various scales. For example, the major scale is two major tetrachords separated by a perfect fifth. Or, the melodic minor scale is a minor tetrachord and a major tetrachord separated by a perfect fifth. Etc. etc.

There is a good theoretical reason to look at scales and tetrachords in that way. Using `C` as tonic, and using only P4 tetrachords, all of the scales thus derived will have principle tones of `C F G C`, or a tonic with two tones a perfect fourth and a perfect fifth above the tonic, which gives us the all important *tonal scale degrees*. From there all the various tones of `D E A B` become effectively the *modal scale degrees*. The method provides more than a whole heap of scales, it provides a framework for understanding the *tonal structure* of the scales.

I'm not saying you shouldn't make your chart, but just pointing out the reason why joining two P4 tetrachords is a common music theory concept.

Comment: I think the first minor tetrachord got a typo, G for F?

Answer (score 1):

From Alfred's Essentials of Music Theory:

> A tetrachord is a series of four notes having a patter of whole step, whole step, half step.  The four notes of a tetrachord must be in alphabetical order.

In a major scale, there are two places this pattern occurs.  Notes 1 to 4, and notes 5 to 8, so it appears twice in a major scale.

I looked at the [Wikipedia Tetrachord definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrachord) which says:

> In music theory, a tetrachord (Greek: τετράχορδoν, Latin: tetrachordum) is a series of four notes separated by three intervals. In traditional music theory, a tetrachord always spanned the interval of a perfect fourth, a 4:3 frequency proportion (approx. 498 cents)—but in modern use it means any four-note segment of a scale or tone row, not necessarily related to a particular tuning system.

While Wikipedia says:

> In traditional music theory, a tetrachord always spanned the interval of a perfect fourth

They don't indicate the pattern of a tetrachord, which I've been taught is important.  The pattern is whole step, whole step, half step.  Also, Wikipedia says:

> **in modern use** it means any four-note segment of a scale or tone row, not necessarily related to a particular tuning system

So I would say that just because someone calls a four note segment a tetrachord doesn't mean that it **is** a tetrachord.

So I guess the useful answer is, know your audience.  If you're being tested in a music theory class there is one **right** answer.  Learn that answer.  When you're in an informal setting with other musicians (who don't know music theory) they might refer to a 4 note sequence as a tetrachord, and you can at least understand what they mean when they say it.

Comment: The definitions (Alfreds and wikipedia) are different.  I believe what I've been taught which is the Alfred's definition is the correct definition.  But I respect others opinions which is why I shared the Wikipedia definition.  In your comment that says I said there are four tetrachords, I think you misunderstood me.  There are two tetrachords in a major scale (1-4 and 5-8), they happen to match the Ionion and Mixolydian modes, but that is unrelated to the definition of a tetrachord (IMO).

Comment: Well, a technicality: I'm not sure that "C-C#-E-F" would be considered a segment of any "scale or tone." If you spelled the C# as Db, presumably it would.

Comment: Actually, as I think about it, maybe [it could be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_row). The usual definition is, in the context of "12-tone" or serial music, a complete set of all 12 chromatic pitches, but arranged in a specific order—a sort of 12-tone "melody." But the Wikipedia sentence wouldn't make sense with that definition, unless you re-ordered them in order of pitch... in which case it's just a chromatic scale. Maybe it used the term more broadly to cover more exotic "scales."

Comment: Yup. My point was that, for most "garden-variety" meanings of "scale," the enharmonic spellings are such that you don't repeat or skip a letter, thus Db instead of C#. Meanwhile, to the big-picture question of "what 'tetrachord' means," I think you're onto it: it can mean *any* 4 neighboring notes, but we talk about the major one so often that sometimes we use it as a shorthand, like saying "C chord" without bothering to say "major."

Comment: So the `tone row` G,Ab,B,C (intervals are half-step, minor 3rd, half-step) are last 4 notes of C harmonic minor scale match this pattern.  See diagram at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_scale.  I don't consider this a tetrachord even though Wikipedia's definition allows it.

Comment: Fair enough. I think "you're both right"; that if you walk up to a random person and ask them "what's a tetrachord" they'd say whole-whole-half, but neither is it out of line to discuss other divisions of the fourth as "other types" of tetrachords.

Comment: @PatS the tone row G-Ab-B-C is m2-A2-m2, you can't say that the interval between Ab & B is minor 3rd, as a minor 3rd would be Ab-Cb, which is en-harmonically the same, but not functionally.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the chart is correct. Here it is recreated in text for future readers.

| Tetrachord | Tone composition | Major | N. Minor | H. Minor | M. Minor (asc.) | H. Major |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ionic | W-W-H | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Doric | W-H-W | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Phrygian | H-W-W | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Lydian | W-W-W | 1 | 1 |  | 2 |  |
| Harmonic | H-A-H |  |  | 1 |  | 1 |
| **Total** |  | **7** | **7** | **4** | **6** | **4** |